Design for LTE - modem, MCU and eSIM - the differences
I'm thinking of a small IoT product and I'm trying to tie together all components that I would need. Simple googling will take me to the product pages of ST4SIM too much rather than help me get an overview of what components I would even need.
I'm looking and comparing the "simple" nRF9160 option and the options where I take an MCU such as STM32, an LTE Module and an eSIM IC.
Can somebody help me and explain the following questions:

An ST4SIM, does it contain an eSIM or would I need an external eSIM.
What is the difference between an ST4SIM and an LTE Module or are they both required in a design?
If it does not contain an eSIM, why would I benefit of this ST4SIM over an LTE Module? What are the differences between the two?
Why would I choose an MCU, an LTE Module and an eSIM over the nRF9160 in my design?

I hope that answers to these questions give me a better understanding of what they do and how they will affect my circuit design.

I'm currently working on an IoT project at work myself as well, so I'm basically going through the same steps you are in trying to architect a unique solution. This is my first time doing an LTE related project as well, so I'll share some of my knowledge so far, without diving into NDA territory:


An ST4SIM, does it contain an eSIM or would I need an external eSIM.


The ST4SIM (something I'm currently looking at as well) has multiple form factors: traditional SIM (2FF, 3FF, and 4FF) and eSIM (MFF2, which is DFN-8-esque and WLCSP24). You wouldn't need an external SIM unless you want to support both options where one can be used instead of the other.


What is the difference between an ST4SIM and an LTE Module or are they both required in a design?


The LTE module basically is the one talks between your SIM card and the radio tower. Your SIM card (whether traditional SIM or eSIM) is the one who tells your modem what bands it's basically allowed to connect to and what the data rate limits are, etc. Think of it like your LTE module asking your SIM, "Hey, I see Bands A, B, and C. Which bands are your customer allowed to connect to?" and then the SIM says, "My customer only pays for a certain carrier, so let's go with Band A." and then from there, there's some handshaking processes like your IMEI and other configurations. They are both required for your design.


If it does not contain an eSIM, why would I benefit of this ST4SIM over an LTE Module? What are the differences between the two?


I don't know any LTE modules that have an eSIM built into it and I doubt you will find anything on the market. Either way, you need both. A lot of modem manufacturers so have some relations with the eSIM provider to ensure cross-compatibility. The difference between the two is mentioned above, in response to your second question.


Why would I choose an MCU, an LTE Module and an eSIM over the nRF9160 in my design?


From what I've experienced so far, some LTE modules can provide some MCU capabilities but there are a lot of issues with that, namely power and performance. It's best to offload your GPIO, UART, etc. transactions from your "things/sensors/actuators/etc." onto another MCU. Not to mention, the amount of memory in the LTE module is very tiny compared to an MCU. The nRF9160 is an LTE module so I'm not entirely sure what your question is asking.

Thank you for this amazing help, really clarifies the bit! The nRF9160 contains an Arm Cortex-M33 cpu for application development. Sounds like some kind of MCU capabilities? Or am I wrong here.
The Arm Cortex-M33 application processor is supported by 1 MB of flash and 256 KB RAM making advanced application development possible in a single device solution.

Also, the question that I think I'm asking is as follows. I think of using an nRF9160 since it is an LTE Module and mcu with gpio in one package if i'm correct. Would I need a normal simple eSIM or would it be best to use an ST4SIM, and why? Would it not suffice to just use the nRF9160 along with a basic eSIM chip?

You're welcome  Your LTE modules will have their own MCU actually. I've seen Cortex as you mentioned but also Andes Core and Sony Altair. These have their own firmware to configure your band support so this is why you probably don't want to use the LTE module alongside more I/O usage. There's other reasons as I mentioned like power. If you're using a battery, it'll drain battery quicker because you have to wake up the modem every time you simply want to use non-modem features. This is why it's recommended to have a separate MCU from your LTE module.

eSIM is good for being able to change carriers on the fly without having to go out into the field and change out an otherwise traditional SIM. This application is really for those who are mass producing their products, like me at work. But for you, if it's a hobby project, then I would probably recommend a traditional SIM. There's also cost benefits as well.... Overall, for your complete design, I would do an MCU then a separate LTE module and then a traditional SIM card. You need all three components.

I wouldn't recommend eSIMs for hobbyists because the registration processes get extremely complicated. I've been talking with STMicro for the last few weeks on getting them to tell me about manufacturing processes and there's a lot to it. You have to maintain an EIM server, you have to get a hash from your LTE module, etc. It's extremely complicated. I would choose your local carrier for a traditional SIM card.
